# Use spread syntax for object literals in webpack configuration files

Tags: webpack

I would like to use spread syntax for object literals in my webpack configuration files.
eg.

```
...isProd ? {
    ...
}:{
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to pass `--harmony_object_rest_spread` flag to node (v8.1.2) through the webpack command line ?

Answer (score 0):

Not strictly an answer to your question regarding spread syntax, but could you instead use `Object.assign()` to achieve the same?